# Ruby Rails Query In conditional

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, querying

I have this query that works but I would like to expand it so that I can check for multiple ids such that I pass in a vector of ids. `[1,2,3,5]` etc... I have tried using SQL `IN` with no luck.

```
EventType.find(3).events.all(:include => {:sheet => :rink}, :conditions => ["rinks.id = ?", 2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with `IN`. Here's syntax that will work in Rails 3+:

```
EventType.find(3).events.where("id IN (?)", [1,2,3]).include(:sheet => :rink)
```

Improvement from a comment removes SQL entirely:

```
EventType.find(3).events.where(:id => [1,2,3]).include(:sheet => :rink)
```

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the parenthesis around ?

Comment: You could also `where(:id => [1,2,3])`